# How do I integrate prerender.io to an nginx config?

Tags: node.js, docker, vue.js, nginx, prerender

I am looking to add prerender.io for better seo since I am running a Vue frontend and Node backend communicating through docker containers on an Nginx server. My understanding is without prerendering or SSR, opengraph tags will not be read by certain bots. SSR is rather involved and not completely necessary thus prerendering seem to be all I need.

Here is my default file:

```
# HTTP - redirect all traffic to HTTPS
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only==on;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS - proxy all requests to Node app
server {
  # Enable Http/2
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
  server-name example.com;

 # USE LETSENCRYPT CERTIFICATES
 ssl_certificate /etc..... .pem;
 ssl_certificate /etc..... .pem;

 # INCLUDE THE SSL CONFIG FROM CIPHERLIST.ST
 include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

 location /api/ {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;
}

 location / {
   proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
   proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
  }
}
```

and here is the snippet from the prerender github: [Nginx/Prerender snippet](https://github.com/prerender/prerender-nginx/blob/master/nginx.conf)

My question is do I splice these snippet parts into the existing blocks or do I add additional http and server blocks. I am novice when it comes to servers and configuring Nginx.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to include prerender.io as a middleware for certain routes in your existing Nginx configuration. You can add a location block for the routes that you want to prerender. This can be done within your existing server block. In your case, you might want to prerender URLs that are meant for SEO purposes. I think something like this could work too,

```
location /seo-page {
    # Specify the Prerender.io server URL
    set $prerender "http://your-prerender-server-url";

    if ($args ~ "_escaped_fragment_") {
        set $prerender "${prerender}${uri}";
    }

    # Check if a user agent should be ignored (e.g., crawlers and bots)
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "googlebot|bingbot|yahoo|baiduspider|yandexbot") {
        set $prerender 0;
    }

    # If $prerender is set, proxy to Prerender.io
    if ($prerender) {
        proxy_set_header X-Prerender-Token "your-prerender-token";
        proxy_pass $prerender;
    }

    # If not, proxy to your Vue.js app
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
    proxy_ssl_session_reuse off;
}
```